# Pointer Based Implementation of BST in Python

Tags: python, pointers, binary-search-tree

I am having trouble understanding the code provided by my coursebook for implementing a BST in Python. I know there are much simpler ways to do it, but the exam questions are based on the approach used in the code below, which emulates using pointers.

One thing that bugs me is that, in a linked list at least, there is no need to use the "previous node/current node inch-worming technique" for insertion, so I'm skeptical about the need the lines like `self.PreviousNodePointer = ThisNodePointer`.I may of course be wrong. I'm guessing maybe we need this inch-worming as we are dealing with an ordered structure? My mistrust of the textbook's solution is based on the fact that it does indeed contain numerous confirmed errors.

Could someone please tell me if the insertion can be done more simply while still using the same basic approach?

```
class TreeNode: # object for each node
    def __init__(self):
        self.Data = ""
        self.LeftPointer = -1
        self.RightPointer = -1

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, n): # initialisation with list length n
        self.null = -1
        self.RootPointer = self.null
        self.FreePointer = 0
        self.Tree = []
        for i in range (0, n):
            self.Tree.append(TreeNode())
            self.Tree[i].LeftPointer = i + 1
        self.Tree[n-1].LeftPointer = self.null

    def display(self): # print a display in order of index positions
        print("{0:^5}|{1:^10}|{2:^10}|{3:^10}|".format("", "Left", "Data", "Right"))
        for i in range (0, len(self.Tree)):
            index = "[" + str(i) + "]"
            print("{0:^5}|{1:^10}|{2:^10}|{3:^10}|".format(index, self.Tree[i].LeftPointer, self.Tree[i].Data, self.Tree[i].RightPointer))
        print("RootPointer:", self.RootPointer)
        print("FreePointer:", self.FreePointer)

    def insert(self, item): # insert item, returns true if inserted and false if set full
        if self.FreePointer == self.null:
            return False # no room in list
        NewNodePointer = self.FreePointer
        # set free pointer to next position in "free list" if that is
        # the right term
        self.FreePointer = self.Tree[self.FreePointer].LeftPointer
        # Add data to node at free node pointer
        self.Tree[NewNodePointer].Data = item
        # Why do we need to set these to null?
        self.Tree[NewNodePointer].LeftPointer = self.null
        self.Tree[NewNodePointer].RightPointer = self.null
        #If this is the first node to be inserted into tree
        if self.RootPointer == self.null:
            self.RootPointer = NewNodePointer
        else:
            ThisNodePointer = self.RootPointer
            while ThisNodePointer != self.null:
                self.PreviousNodePointer = ThisNodePointer
                if self.Tree[ThisNodePointer].Data > item:
                    self.TurnedLeft = True
                    ThisNodePointer = self.Tree[ThisNodePointer].LeftPointer
                else:
                    self.TurnedLeft = False
                    ThisNodePointer = self.Tree[ThisNodePointer].RightPointer
            if self.TurnedLeft:
                self.Tree[self.PreviousNodePointer].LeftPointer = NewNodePointer
            else:
                self.Tree[self.PreviousNodePointer].RightPointer = NewNodePointer
        return True

    def find(self, item): # returns position of an item, -1 if not found
        ThisNodePointer = self.RootPointer
        while ThisNodePointer != self.null and self.Tree[ThisNodePointer].Data != item:
            if self.Tree[ThisNodePointer].Data > item:
                ThisNodePointer = self.Tree[ThisNodePointer].LeftPointer
            else:
                ThisNodePointer = self.Tree[ThisNodePointer].RightPointer
        return ThisNodePointer

#######################
##  Example commands ##
#######################

MyTree = BinaryTree(6) # Create a tree of length 6
MyTree.display() # display tree in a table
MyTree.insert(10) # insert number 10
MyTree.insert(40)
MyTree.insert(30)
MyTree.insert(50)
MyTree.insert(60)
MyTree.display()
print("Item found at position", MyTree.find(30)) # print the position of number 30
```

Comment: Did you try writing test cases for you class? And verifying?

Comment: I've tried tracing the execution.It is surprising difficult to trace, for me at least. The code is much more complex than everything else in the syllabus.

Comment: You know about BSTs theoritically, right? Use that knowledge to write a test-case. Assert for something like: "given these series of inputs, the tree should look like this" and that should match with whatever tree you would expect - theoritically

Comment: Here's a standard implementation in java: https://www.techiedelight.com/insertion-in-bst/ go through it and see if that's doing what you're doing